# Create bash script to connect to six remote servers

Tags: bash, expect

this script allows me to connect to a remote server. I want to transform it to connect to six remote servers to be able to load data from these servers. Someone can give me a direction.

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
        set username "username"
        set password "password"
        set hosts "hostname"
        spawn ssh  $username@$hosts
        expect "$username@$hosts's password:"
        send -- "$password\n"
        expect "$password"
        sleep 20
    
    send -- "exit\n"
```

Comment: Do you want it to be parallel or connecting 1 after the other is okay? If serial is okay, you can have an array with the six ips and then loop through them while executing the code that you already have

Comment: Hi @abhishek phukan, I want it to be parallel

Comment: Why do you use expect?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, expect allows me to answer automatically to questions, when i need to put password or any other things.

Comment: For Parallel execution you can use https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/. This should help

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi there, cant comment yet so i will answer here.
2. First if the connection is needed by default (every time your machine is on) it is recommended to use an autossh service.

   - you can find an example and guide for autossh service here [autosshExample](https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9707568)
   - after writing that service you can run it with systemctl option serviceName.service
   - the service will allow the machine to auto run the service when shes turning on.
3. Another way to solve that problem ( a primitive but working one) is:

   - make a script that running other scripts.
   - make script for each server and then a script to run all the scripts: (use the path to the script to execute them one after the other).

```
#/bin/bash!
    /usr/local/sbin/./scriptOne
    sleep 10
    /usr/local/sbin/./scriptTwo
    sleep 10
    /usr/local/sbin/./scriptThree
```

4. To run the ssh's parallel you can use this options:

   - run the scripts from the main script with &
   - for example `/usr/local/sbin/scriptOne && /usr/local/sbin/scriptTwo`
   - because its an ssh service then you should use a flag to not open a new terminal and run the process at the background to avoid errors.
   - **use the flags -f -n in your ssh's scripts to avoid opening new terminal windows.**
   - this should allow you to run few ssh's process from the same terminal windows by sending each command and process to run on the background.
   - **also note that using ssh keys instead of password is more safety.**

Comment: Hi @CrazyTux, the connection is not necessary by default. I want to execute it, i want  it to be  parallel .

Comment: i edited my answer, you can run few ssh's from one script parallel. If something is not understood I am here to help

Comment: by sending the command to the background , you will not be able to track it later properly

Comment: @abhishekphukan well you can find the command with `pgrep -a ssh`, then you will get the full command and the PID, if the only thing Justin wants is to have an access to the servers that should work out, but it is true there are more ways to handle that problem.

Comment: @JustinCoulibaly i still recommend to create a ssh or autossh service, then you could start the connection withing the command `systemctl start/stop serviceName.service` this is the cleanest and the best way i can think about to solve that issue.

Comment: Hi CrazyTux, I have some questions and some problems about the output of ssh script.

Comment: Please add the problems to your question or comment them so i could try to help out.